# POA ethereum Add Authority Account Contract

Tags: private-blockchain

Can someone point me right tutorial to understand the following

1) Genesis configuration for POA with pre-fund account

2) How to add Authority account at run time means once the blockchain is up and running

3) Sample working contract for same where user can vote to add new authority account.

Comment: What PoA are you referring to? Aura? Clique?

Comment: @GiuseppeBertone We are using Aura